# converting c# timestamp to datetime in php

Tags: c#, php, datetime

I have timestamp comoing from c# (64-bit binary value) that I need to convert in php.
The timestamp is created with DateTime.ToBinary() method.
an example is -8586307756854775808 which gives 10/11/2019 10:00:00 PM

I tried with unpack() in php but without success:

```
$timestamp = unpack('q', -8586307756854775808);
```

How can I do this in php ? 
Thanks

Comment: You're misunderstanding what ToBinary does, read the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tobinary?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: To "0001-01-01 00:00:00" add `(num & 0xfffffffffffffff)/10000` milis it should be UTC time

Comment: @Selvin - The mask would need to be `0x3fffffffffffffff` to separate ticks from kind correctly, but even then [there's more logic required](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,d1e0507af2af9286).  Without evaluating the kind, there's no guarantee those are UTC based. 
 It's really not a good idea to be using this format anyway, unless it's being passed back to `FromBinary` in C#.

Comment: [AFAIK it's always UTC](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,c6309e27def6368e,references) the mask is only needed to eventually set DateTime to local if you use FromBinary ... but he want to get this in PHP so it's irevellant

Comment: Nope.  `DateTimeKind` has four possible values.  `Unspecified`, `Utc`, `Local`, and a [fourth "hidden" variation of `Local`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,40).  (See also "DateTime’s Deep Dark Secret" in [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime/))

Comment: See also (the comments on the internal [`DateTime.dateData` field](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,132).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first must separate the ticks from 64-bit binary value.
The ticks of the 64-bit value are the same when creating DateTime in C#  regardless of the use of DateTimeKind.Utc or DateTimeKind.Local 
Then may be convert the Ticks in a UNIX-Timestamp. 
gmdate() returns a date string from the timestamp.

```
<?php
//num from c# DateTime.ToBinary() 
//2019-10-11 22:00:00
$num = -8586307756854775808;

$ticks = $num & 0x3fffffffffffffff;
$linuxTs = $ticks/10000000 - 62135596800;
$strDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",$linuxTs);

echo $strDate; //"2019-10-11 22:00:00"
```

Note: This solution requires a 64-bit platform.

The kind information from the 64-bit value $num may also be useful.

```
$kind = (ord(pack('J',$num)) & 0xC0)>>6;  //0,1 or 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.ToBinary` creates a value that combines the `.Ticks` and `.Kind` property into a single 64-bit value.  You shouldn't use it unless you intend to pass that value back into `DateTime.FromBinary` in .NET.

While it is *possible* to interpret it outside of .NET, one would have to apply the same logic that is in the implementation of `DateTime.FromBinary`.  [You can see the source code here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,d1e0507af2af9286).

Instead, consider using a standard interchange format.  The most common is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (also covered in part by [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)).

```
string iso = dateTime.ToString("O");
```

The above uses [the "round-trip" specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier) to get the ISO 8601 format.  There are other ways as well.

If your values are UTC based, you could also consider passing a [Unix Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  The simplest way to get one from .NET is through `DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds` or `DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds` depending on what precision you want.  Of course, you will need to convert your `DateTime` to a `DateTimeOffset` first.

```
long ms = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

The above assumes that your `DateTime` has either `DateTimeKind.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Utc` in its `.Kind` property.  If it is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, then you may need to work with `TimeZoneInfo` to get aligned to UTC before figuring out the Unix Timestamp.